# C# XML Deserialization into multiple objects

Tags: c#, xml

I am deserializing a given XML file into a single object, which I have working fine. However, I now which to adapt the XML file so that I extra attributes, which should be deserialized into a separate object, so from the one given xml file i can populate two objects, is this possible within one operation?

Here is my current code and XML:

XML As it is now:

```
<NameCollection>
   <Names>
      <Name>
        <description></description>
      <Name>
      <Name>
        <description></description>
      <Name>
   </Names>
</NameCollection>
```

XML As I wish it to be:

```
<NameCollection>
  <GenericName></GenericName>
  <GenericDescription></GenericDescription>
   <Names>
      <Name>
        <description></description>
      <Name>
      <Name>
        <description></description>
      <Name>
   </Names>
</NameCollection>
```

Code:

```
NameCollection commands;

XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(typeof(NameCollection));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(xmlpath);

commands = (NameCollection)serializer.Derserialize(streamreader);

streamReader.Close();
```

And the current object:

```
[Serializable()]
public class TestCommand
{
   public string description{get;set;}
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("NameCollection")]
public class NameCollection
{
   [XmlArray("Commands")]
   [XmlArrayItem("Command", typeof(TestCommand))]
   public TestCommand[] TestCommand {get;set;}
}
```

I then wish to add GenericName and GenericDescription attributes to another separate object, this is what im stuck on.

Comment: What you mean by *another separate object* and how's it related to `NameCollection`?

Comment: Everything you have there should already work (if we assume Name/Names === Command/Commands); you should just need to add `public string GenericName {get;set;}` and `public string GenericDescription {get;set;}` to `NameCollection`...?

Comment: TestCommand object stores the description attribute. I would like a new object to hold <GenericName></GenericName> and <GenericDescription></GenericDescription> attributes, however Im not sure how this could be accomplished.

Comment: As a side note: `XmlSerializer` does not require `[Serializable]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your after is to have your class reflect the structure of the XML, rather than two classes. So you want a structure like:

```
public class TestCommand
{
   public string description{get;set;}
}

[XmlRoot("NameCollection")]
public class NameCollection
{
    public string GenericName {get; set;}
    public string GenericDescription {get; set;}

   [XmlArray("Commands")]
   [XmlArrayItem("Command", typeof(TestCommand))]
   public TestCommand[] TestCommand {get;set;}
}
```

then serialize it in exactly the same way, job done.

Answer (score 2):

With the layout you have, the only place `XmlSerializer` is going to want to put those extra values is on `NameCollection`, i.e.

```
[XmlRoot("NameCollection")]
public class NameCollection
{
    public string GenericName {get;set:}
    public string GenericDescription {get;set:}

    [XmlArray("Names")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Name", typeof(TestCommand))]
    public TestCommand[] TestCommand {get;set;}
}
```

If you want it to go on some other object, then: `XmlSerializer` isn't going to do that.

Comment: @Liam I think you said it 30 seconds sooner, but: sometimes it is worth hearing the same thing twice from 2 independent sources, as cross-validation that they're not making it up.